# Preprocessing to get rid of not hyphen but dash in sentences

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, character, processing

## What I would like to do

I would like to get rid of not hyphen but dash in sentences for NLP preprocessing.

**Input**

```
samples = [
    'A former employee of the accused company, ———, offered a statement off the record.', #three dashes
    'He is afraid of two things — spiders and senior prom.' #dash
    'Fifty-six bottles of pop on the wall, fifty-six bottles of pop.' #hyphen
]
```

**Expected Output**

```
#output
['A former employee of the accused company','offered a statement off the record.']
['He is afraid of two things', 'spiders and senior prom.']
['Fifty-six bottles of pop on the wall', 'fifty-six bottles of pop.']
```

The above sentences are from the following two articles about hyphen and dash.

- [Grammarly Blog Dashes](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/dash/)
- [Grammarly Blog Hyphen](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/hyphen/)

## Problem

1. The first process to get rid of the symbol '-' was failed, and it is difficult to understand the reason why the second and third sentence were combined without single quotation ('').

```
#output
['A former employee of the accused company, — — —, offered a statement off the record.', 
'He is afraid of two things—spiders and senior prom.
Fifty-six bottles of pop on the wall, fifty-six bottles of pop.']
```

2. I have no idea how I can write code to distinguish hyphen and dash.

## Current Code

```py
samples = [
    'A former employee of the accused company, — — —, offered a statement off the record.', #dash
    'He is afraid of two things—spiders and senior prom.' #dash
    'Fifty-six bottles of pop on the wall, fifty-six bottles of pop.' #hyphen
]

ignore_symbol = ['-']
for i in range(len(samples)):
    text = samples[i]
    ret = []
    for word in text.split(' '):
        ignore = len(word) <= 0 
        for iw in ignore_symbol:
            if word == iw:
                ignore = True
                break
        if not ignore:
            ret.append(word)

    text = ' '.join(ret)
    samples[i] = text
print(samples)

#output
['A former employee of the accused company, — — —, offered a statement off the record.', 
'He is afraid of two things—spiders and senior prom.
Fifty-six bottles of pop on the wall, fifty-six bottles of pop.']

for i in range (len(samples)):
    list_temp = []
    text = samples[i]
    list_temp.extend([x.strip() for x in text.split(',') if not x.strip() == ''])
    samples[i] = list_temp
print(samples)

#output
[['A former employee of the accused company',
  '— — —',
  'offered a statement off the record.'],
 ['He is afraid of two things—spiders and senior prom.Fifty-six bottles of pop on the wall',
  'fifty-six bottles of pop.']]
```

## Develop Environment

Python 3.7.0

Comment: `distinguish hyphen and dash` - can you describe in words the difference between a hyphen and a dash? Are you familiar with regular expressions?

Comment: In your example text the *hyphens* are Unicode code point `45` and the dashes are Unicode code point `8212` - is your example a copy and paste from your real text? .. `for c in s: print(c,ord(c))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for non-regex solution, Unicode point for dash is [`8212`](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2014), so you can replace those with `','`, then split by `','` and then add non-whitespace sentences:

```
>>> samples = [
    'A former employee of the accused company, ———, offered a statement off the record.', #three dashes
    'He is afraid of two things — spiders and senior prom.', #dash
    'Fifty-six bottles of pop on the wall, fifty-six bottles of pop.' #hyphen
]
>>> output = [[
               sentence.strip() for sentence in elem.replace(chr(8212), ',').split(',') 
               if sentence.strip()
              ] for elem in samples]
>>> output
[['A former employee of the accused company',
  'offered a statement off the record.'],
 ['He is afraid of two things', 'spiders and senior prom.'],
 ['Fifty-six bottles of pop on the wall', 'fifty-six bottles of pop.']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying using a regex (regular expression) split with `re.split`. Python's String.split() is too limited in functionality for this. You'll then need to pass the Unicode version of a "hyphen" character.

Something like:

```
re.split('[\002D]', text)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the 2nd and 3rd sentence were combined because there is no comma separating both the strings. In Python, writing `tmp = 'a''b'` is equivalent to `tmp = 'ab'`, which is why there are just 2 strings in the `samples` (2nd and 3rd got merged).

Onto to your question:
Function `remove_dash_preserve_hyphen` below removes all dashes in the `str_sentence` parameter and returns a cleaned `str_sentence`.
The function is then applied to all string elements in the `samples` list, thus generating the clean `samples_without_dash`.

```
samples = [
    'A former employee of the accused company, ———, offered a statement off the record.', #three dashes
    'He is afraid of two things — spiders and senior prom.',#**(COMMA HERE)** #dash
    'Fifty-six bottles of pop on the wall, fifty-six bottles of pop.' #hyphen
]

def remove_dash_preserve_hyphen(str_sentence, dash_signatures=['—']):
    for dash_sig in dash_signatures:
        str_sentence = str_sentence.replace(dash_sig, '')
    return str_sentence

samples_without_dash = [remove_dash_preserve_hyphen(sentence) for sentence in samples]
```

The exact dash in question is the 'em-dash' with unicode 'U+2014'.
It could be possible that there's more kind of dashes in the samples, that you don't want. You need to track it down sample wise, and pass the list of all dash types (the ones you don't want) in `dash_signatures` parameter while calling the `remove_dash_preserve_hyphen` function.